# htaccess redirect for https, www, no trailing slash on files

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to force my urls to https, www and no trailing slashes.
Since I have multiple domains that point to this page, a static domain in there is no option.
This is what i have so far:

```
# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works quite well, except for the case:

```
https://www.example.com//
```

which redirects to:

```
https://www.www.example.com/
```

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?
Also from a redirects perspective I'm not really sure if this will make 3 redirects in the worst case and can somehow be improved to only one redirect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How relevant is `https://www.example.com//` to begin with - do you have any links explicitly pointing to this? _“Also from a redirects perspective I'm not really sure if this will make 3 redirects in the worst case”_ - use your browser dev tools’ network panel, or an external redirect checker, and find out …

Comment: thanks for your reply!
`https://www.example.com//` is relevant from an SEO perspective as I understood.. It makes sure that not both urls can be indexed and you do not end up with duplicate content..

Comment: Yes, but search engines do not make up URLs on their own. Someone would have to supply them with this incorrect URL in the first place. So where would they pick this up from in the first place, and why does it not get corrected there then?

Comment: Parts of what you currently have their don’t make the most sense to begin with. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$` – why would the host name of the request ever be _empty_? And that check for HTTPS is also rather weird. What is the purpose of catching that `s` and inserting `%1` in the substitution URL? You _always_ want to redirect to the HTTPS version of your site, so what purpose does it serve to even have the option of rewriting to HTTP in that place?

Comment: Potentially competitors can supply them with those kind of urls, no?

Comment: and i'm really not an htaccess or regex pro at all, thats why i ended up here, desperate for some advice. what i have in that current htaccess is what i tried to copy together and made most sense to me.

All i would like to make is a working htaccess, that always forces https and www and removes trailing slashes in any request (also for subsites)..

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found something else which seems to make more sense

```
# force https and www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now the only remaining problems are the following two requests:

```
http://www.example.com
```

which redirects to https://www.www.example.com

and

```
https://www.example.com//
```

which does not remove the multiple slashes.

any ideas? would really appreciate help!